# NiFi what are the list of action to do in case of processor hang up?

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi 1.5 (3 node cluster)

some of the processors like (UpdateAttribute and HandleHTTPRequest) in my flow got hang up. once i stop these processors, there is no option to start it again.

i know that, restarting the NiFi would release the processor from hang state. i am keeping this as last option since many projects would be affected in the production.

other option is, clearing the provenance directory from the system. since many projects are involved in NiFi, i am not sure of clearing the provenance.

what are the other ways to consider or i should be checking to release the hang state.

Comment: Are there errors in the logs? What does the logs say?

Comment: Could you give a bit more context to what kind of flow it is, what kind of files are going through the flow and what are you trying to do with the UpdateAttribute and HandleHTTPRequest processor. 
And when you say "hang up", what do you mean?

Comment: there are no logs are captured in nifi-app.log.

Comment: the flow is getting the file from ftp server -> routeonattribute -> updateattribute ->  puthdfs. but only this updateattribute is hanged up. like i mentioned above, there is different flow where request comes from portal to HandleHTTPRequest -> routeonattribute -> gethdfs -> HandleHTTPResponse. when i say hanged up, it means that i dont see any option to start/stop the processor. currently it is in stop state, i dont see option to start it again.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the processor in question and click "Terminate" if it's present.

When NiFi processors are stopped, they still cling to the task they were working on, presumably to close the flow file.  If that fails or hangs or otherwise doesn't complete in a reasonable time frame, the processor won't allow you to restart it.  Terminating the task forces the issue (and potentially loses the data for the flow file, but that risk seems unavoidable at this point).